# Got revival badge even though mine was not the first answer

Tags: support, badges

I answered [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505028/express-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu/23275418#23275418) a while ago. Today I got this notification:

> You've earned the "Revival" badge (Answered more than 30 days later as
>   first answer scoring 2 or more) for "Express doesn't work on ubuntu

Now what I understand from this is that if you answer to a non-answered question after a month of being asked on SO and get up votes you get this badge. But my answer definitely wasn't the first one. So how did I get this badge, which I probably shouldn't have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> first answer scoring 2

This doesn't mean the first answer posted must score 2, but the first answer that reaches the score of 2.

So as long as your answer hits 2+ before all the others, you'll get the badge.

Comment: oh! thanks :) that clarifies. I will accept answer after 10 minutes.